# TypeScript `asserts` on global type

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of places in my code where I rely on an environment variable and want to throw an error if it does not exist:

```
if(!process.env.SOME_VAR) {
  throw new Error('Missing required environment variable "SOME_VAR"');
}

doSomethingWithVar(process.env.SOME_VAR);

// function doSomethingWithVar(var: string);
```

I was wondering if there was a way to utilize TypeScript's `asserts`-keyword to write a function to do the assertion for me? Something like

```
function assertEnvironmentVariable<T extends string>(name: T):
  asserts NodeJS.ProcessEnv[name] is string {
  if(!process.env[name]) {
    throw new Error(`Missing required environment variable "${name}"`);
  }
}

// Usage:
assertEnvironmentVariable('SOME_VAR');

// no type error here since `assertEnvironmentVariable` already made sure it exists
doSomethingWithVar(process.env.SOME_VAR);
```

However, this definition of `assertEnvironmentVariable` does not work - is this possible at all?

Edit: [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-k7ASCwZDMAcGCZMHHkEHHvsDjLqfL8pFiCm40HQMIAHJqFmsSxGgRAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution without using `asserts` would be:

```
function getEnvironmentVariable(name: string): string {
    const value = process.env[name];
    if(!value) {
        throw new Error(`Missing required environment variable "${name}"`);
    }
    return value;
}

const value = getEnvironmentVariable("SOME_VAR");
doSomethingWithVar(value);
```

Comment: This is actually way simpler and more understandable. Had the same realization 5min after I had typed out the question :D

It does not answer the original question though, so I'll keep it open in case someone can figure out the typings for other people who have a similar problem. If I don't get any answers, I'll accept it later.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to change how you're asserting:

```js
function assertEnvironmentVariable(name: string | number): asserts name is keyof typeof process.env {
    // If you're going to assert a type, you should probably actually
    // assert the type of the thing.
    if (typeof process.env[name] !== 'string' || !process.env[name]) {
        // You don't *have* to use a TypeError, but it makes sense
        throw new TypeError(`Missing required environment variable ${name}`);
    }
}

assertEnvironmentVariable('someVar');

console.log(process.env.someVar); // No type error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=51&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEE0HsFdQE0gOwOQBdSIKabqVALASwGdQAbQrAGlENWVMr30w0jldQE8AHTYgFAhQASVAAraMXQBDOB1wsATp0ihiM1CQBmXZqwDGkALY9CZTEvWUDmIWADuhmSnSVpMsmVqJ9oHmQyXADmSjCIcAB0AkaI0v5htsTEAFygAN4CoNmgmIgAbmmZOSWgANoA1phcadJKlMEAurWo9YjBWTkAvgJdoAC8GZ3ZeYUZPV0A3AIC2tCIBlpIoDLJlqgAogWEYYjGeagAajL1MgBGFgAUiDL7LW3BoAA+GNDGZ5YAlGmrxOukN32tFIVS4kG0eF4mHBCUgSWIkVGQ2yhAhl24fBhPES-ARozKgMwjVAAEJ+oMGK0Gshni8Sdi4bjEQUCbciZ9kaUCGEHBhMLyACpQjZKMJKS4AAwAsiRiA1QCoAI7QHY4XLbXb7RDofInQjnCygAAk6UJXQln2m2QmM1+6y2+R2SC1Rz1BswlwYJkwxyUyEtM1ixEgFkiZEgwUuDPhzPykWD+19ltAwgAcmoMaxLGKBEA)

I *think* that should get you there. Note that like a type predicate this is you saying to the compiler "hey I'm verifying this at runtime" meaning that it's on you to actually make sure you're checking what you think you are.

Comment: Man, I almost thought this was it, but sadly it's not working. It only works in your playground link because you originally typed `process.env` too strict. I edited my question to include a playground link where it's breaking.

Comment: @DeX3 I'll take a look and update if I can fix it, but my typing of process.env I'm pretty sure is how it's actually typed.

Comment: The actual type of `process.env` is `Dict<string>` as per https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/process.d.ts#L111, which is defined here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/node/globals.d.ts#L278

So, the `undefined` is definitely there.